# mod_rewrite from URL to GET variable

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

If someone tries to access this page:

www.myhomepage.com/m/40921

I want the URL (above) to remain the same but the content should be from this page:

www.myhomepage.com/msg?t=40921

Answer (score 1):

If it must be **exactly** like you said, then use this

```
RewriteRule ^m/([0-9]+)\/?$ msg?t=$1
```

But I think you made a typing error. Shouldn't it be `msg.php`? If so, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^m/([0-9]+)\/?$ msg.php?t=$1
```

And in your php file, you can get the  `t` with  `$_GET['t']`.

Comment: On my server I need a slash before the "m" to work: ^/m/([0-9]+)\.php/?$ msg.php?t=$1